# Are open-ended questions allowed for an interview focused on corpus creation?

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, lexicon, corpus-linguistics

NOTE: I am not a linguist, but my interest is in the Natural Language Processing (NLP) field.

I am doing a research which is focused only on gathering new or distinct words on a recently described language. The original lexicon contains only about 1500 words, so my goal is to increase its size by using NLP methods.

Is it appropriate to craft open-ended questions that explicitly elicit words about people, places, animals, plants, events, legends, myths, superstitions, etc. AND use random (unlabeled but familiar) images such as (birds, people, emotions, etc.) when interviewing native speakers?

Based on my searches in the internet (https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/tools-at-lingboard/questionnaires.php), the questionnaires available are linguist-centric and are dedicated to really describe/document a language with focus on linguistic features such as morphosyntax. However (maybe I haven't searched more), I haven't seen a reliable resource that explicitly tells that informal and/or natural conversations is OK for a scholarly study.

Example questions (in vernacular):

1. Do you know names about endemic animals/plants?
2. What plants can be used as medicine/poison?
3. Do you know the names of the places here in your community?
4. How many times do you usually leave your community?
5. Where do you usually go?
   etc...

Comment: You need to look into surveys that use qualitative versus quantitative methods. You can structure your questionnaire **any way you see fit**, it it works for your statistical purposes.